# Why MS Windows "Open with" option does not realize image path?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Hello everybody!

I am coding simple GUI application using...
- PyQt 5
- Python 3.4
- Windows 7

My project has "img" sub folder that includes icon images.

At first I've created batch file to run program in the same folder.

file name: run_app.bat
file text: py myapp.py

This batch file works properly. But this way of running shows cmd windows and it disappears when myapp.py program has finished. I don't want to show this cmd window.

So, I used "Open with" option and link to pythonw.exe. This also has worked right but didn't realize image path. So all the icon images are disappeared.

In the code, I used the relative path like 'img/open_dir.png'. But when I fixed relative path to absolute path and run myapp.py by "Open with", icons shows again.

**What makes this difference?**

I don't want to change relative path to absolute path. Because the program's path can varies time to time.

**Is there a way to fix this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths are always relative to the *current working directory*.  This is not necessarily the directory where your script lives, unless you `cd`'d to that directory and ran the script.  By default, most programs are launched with a current working directory of the user's home directory.

A common idiom to construct paths relative to the script path is to use the `__file__` attribute of a python module.  This still allows you to construct relative paths that will still work even if you move your imgs and scripts to another directory.

```
import os
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
img_path = os.path.join(root, 'img/open_dir.png')
```

Comment: Thank you Brendan. The common idiom to construct relative path you suggested is great hint! My issue has solved!